# What is condition for always be negative/ positive quartic equation?

Tags: inequality, physics

I have a parametric quartic equation. It is potential of a black hole that I want to always be negative. I thought to make it to two quadratic equation. But it is very difficult to solve. What can I do?

My equation is:
$-(\alpha) r^4 +(\alpha( L-a)^2 -2) r^2 +(L^2) r -2(L-a)^2$

This is black hole effective potential which I want to be always negative. α is the intensity of dark energy, a is spin of the black hole and L is particle angular momentum. For Kerr black hole effective potential is a quadratic equation and we know for always negative potential, discriminant must be negative when the coefficient of $r^2$ is negative. Then we get a relation for $L$. For this black hole, I want such $L$  in other variables except for $r$. It means $L(\alpha, a)$. ((In Kerr black hole it was $L(a)$.))

Comment: Please add more information to this post. Could you show the expression you want to keep negative explicitly?

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You mean you want to keep some quartic polynomial to be negative always?  If so there is no equation.  Can you write in more detail exactly what is it that you want to do?  If in general, I would just say the negative of that quartic can be expressed as a sum of squares at least one of which is positive, and you are done.

Comment: I've edited my text. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information.  Because a polynomial is a continuous function, it is sufficient (for the purpose of showing it's always negative) to show it is negative *somewhere* and that it has no *real roots*.  I'd recommend slightly editing the Question to emphasize that the problem concerns treating the expression as a *quartic polynomial* in variable $r$.

Comment: This paper seems to contain the relevant condition: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.10922.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Prakhar's comment is essentially the answer. Whether or not it's *helpful* is up for debate.

**Details:** Given a quartic $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, consider the following auxiliary variables:

\begin{align} 
\Delta\ =\ &256 a^3 e^3 - 192 a^2 b d e^2 - 128 a^2 c^2 e^2 + 144 a^2 c d^2 e - 27 a^2 d^4 \\ 
&+ 144 a b^2 c e^2 - 6 a b^2 d^2 e - 80 a b c^2 d e + 18 a b c d^3 + 16 a c^4 e \\
&- 4 a c^3 d^2 - 27 b^4 e^2 + 18 b^3 c d e - 4 b^3 d^3 - 4 b^2 c^3 e + b^2 c^2 d^2 \\
D =\ &8ac-3b^2 \\
P =\ &b^3+8da^2-4abc
\end{align}

The quartic is negative everywhere *if and only if:* $\Delta$ is positive, **and** at least one of $P$ or $D$ is positive as well, and $a$ is negative. Notice that in your situation $b=0$, so we can simplify slightly:

\begin{align} 
\Delta\ =\ &256 a^3 e^3 - 128 a^2 c^2 e^2 + 144 a^2 c d^2 e - 27 a^2 d^4 \\ 
& + 16 a c^4 e \\
&- 4 a c^3 d^2 \\
D =\ &8ac \\
P =\ &8da^2
\end{align}

The simplification on $P$ and $D$ helps a bit: in particular we know that $P = 8\alpha^2L^2 \geq 0$, with equality if and only if $L=0$ or $\alpha=0$. I suspect that both of those conditions are unphysical, but if not, you'd have to do some thinking about $D$.

So $P$ is positive, and $a=-\alpha$ is negative, so we "only" need to check if $\Delta$ is positive. Unfortunately, substituting in the other variables gives a degree-10 inequality in $L$. It's possible that some careful and smart analysis can give you at least sufficient conditions that don't look horrifying. But especially without having physical intuition on this system, I'm inclined to look for a different path at this point.

Comment: Update: I'm pretty sure that if $r$ is unconstrained then it is possible to make this quartic positive at some points, for any choice of $L$, $a$, and $\alpha$; even assuming $r>0$ and $\alpha>0$. If we had some relation on $L$ and $a$ we might be able to say something better.